# Better alternative for NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

I'm just wondering, is there a better, more efficient function to use than NSTimer? I have a NSTimer code like this on my ViewDidLoad function:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900.0f target:self selector:@selector(methodToRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

With the function methodToRun:

```
-(void)methodToRun {
     if(currentTime == presetTime) {
        //do something
     }
}
```

This works fine but the problem is, this eats up a lot of memory and I am getting memory warnings. So, what's a better, more efficient and less memory consuming way of triggering my methodToRun continuously to check if the currentTime is equal to presetTime?

Comment: If you're getting memory warnings, it's not because of this NSTimer

Comment: You realize that this is not "calling the method continuously" right?  In fact it won't call it at all under 900 seconds later.

Comment: The code you wrote is just creating a timer scheduled, it does not take that much memory which can cause memory warnings. You should probably check other allocated resources to trace this.

Comment: also currentTime == presetTime is probably a bad way to check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grand Central Dispatch alternative to using an NSTimer - invalidating multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699014/grand-central-dispatch-alternative-to-using-an-nstimer-invalidating-multiple-t)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `dispatch_after`.

An alternative solution to this can be achieved by using the dispatch_after method and a weak pointer to self.

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
__block void (^timer)(void) = ^{

    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        id strongSelf = weakSelf;

        if (!strongSelf) {
            return;
        }

        // Schedule the timer again
        timer();

        // Always use strongSelf when calling a method or accessing an iVar
        [strongSelf doSomething];
        strongSelf->anIVar = 0;
    });
};

// Start the timer for the first time
timer();
```

With this you will have a scheduled task that will be called at every sec, it will not retain the target (self) and it will end itself if the target is deallocated.

Source:[NSTimer alternative](http://codeshaker.blogspot.in/2012/07/nstimer-alternative.html)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: This is completely Copy+Paste from source, I didn't changed anything, as I dont want to take ownership and credits for someone else's blog.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Anoop's answer here is swift version:

```
func timerGCD() -> ()
{
    weak var weakSelf = self

    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            if let strongSelf = weakSelf
            {
                // Always use strongSelf when calling a method or accessing an iVar
                strongSelf.doSomething()

                // Schedule the timer again
                strongSelf.timerGCD()
            }
    }
}
```

And then simply start it with:

```
    timerGCD()
```

Answer (score 0):

Better swift version using optional chaining and weak self

```
    func timerGCD() -> ()
    {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue())
            { [weak self] in
                    self?.doSomething()
                    // Schedule the timer again
                    self?.timerGCD()
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

Just run a while loop, and use `sleep()` or `usleep()` functions at the end of the loop which will define the time interval.
PS: don't do it on main thread
**Edit:** I see that I am getting downvotes, but can somebody tell me what is wrong with this approach?