# Grand Central Dispatch alternative to using an NSTimer - invalidating multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, photosframework

I have an issue with a `dispatch_source_t` I'm trying to use. I'm wanting to use it to delay the processing of a `PHChange` for 5 seconds because a `PHChange` can happen multiple times in a short span. I'd appreciate any help offered. Essentially I want to cancel the prior `dispatch_source_t` timer almost like an `NSTimer`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t libraryChangedTimer;

dispatch_source_t CreateTimerDispatchSource(uint64_t interval, uint64_t leeway, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);

    if (timer)
    {
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);

        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);

        dispatch_resume(timer);
    }

    return timer;
}

- (void)libraryChanged:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    NSLog(@"Called immediately and it shouldn't");
}

- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    if (self.libraryChangedTimer)
    {
        dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);

        self.libraryChangedTimer = CreateTimerDispatchSource(5ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^
        {
            [self libraryChanged:changeInstance];
            dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        self.libraryChangedTimer = CreateTimerDispatchSource(5ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^
        {
            [self libraryChanged:changeInstance];
            dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a drop-in GCD-based timer class you can freely use in your app: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p784smackMe/ch35p1041smackMe/MyTimer.swift

Comment: A `dispatch_source_t` cannot be `strong` or `retain` in Xcode 7.1.1. Your code will not compile.

Comment: @Cœur - No, that's not true. If you're seeing that error, it's probably because you set compiler flag `-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0`, which as described in `<os/object.h>`, turns off object behavior for GCD types. But I retested this in Xcode 7.1.1 (as well as Xcode 7.2 beta 3), and `strong` works fine.

Comment: You'll also get this error if you target OS X versions prior to 10.8 or iOS versions prior to 6, as that predates the object handling of GCD types, and thus requires manual `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`.

Comment: You're right, I was targeting iOS5. Code is fine when targeting iOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out quite simply with using `dispatch_after` Code:

```
dispatch_source_t CreateTimerDispatchSource(uint64_t interval, uint64_t leeway, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);

    if (timer)
    {
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, leeway);

        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval), queue,^
        {
            dispatch_resume(timer);
        });
    }

    return timer;
}

- (void)libraryChanged:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    // Do something 
}

- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    if (self.libraryChangedTimer)
    {
        dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);

        self.libraryChangedTimer = CreateTimerDispatchSource(5ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^
        {
            [self libraryChanged:changeInstance];
            dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);
            self.libraryChangedTimer = nil;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        self.libraryChangedTimer = CreateTimerDispatchSource(5ull * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^
        {
            [self libraryChanged:changeInstance];
            dispatch_source_cancel(self.libraryChangedTimer);
            self.libraryChangedTimer = nil;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this line:

```
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);
```

You are specifying, in effect, "now" as the timer's start time. That's what `dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0)` calculates. You are passing your `interval` value as the timer's interval, which is asking it to repeat with that period between firings. But the start time determines the time of the *first* firing.

What you wanted was:

```
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, interval), interval, leeway);
```

Or, if you don't actually want the timer to repeat:

```
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, interval), DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, leeway);
```